# How do you take imported data and and break the data into two lists, one even numbers and one odd numbers

Tags: physics

Trying to use the simpsons rule to look at work done for a dragged chain

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you please provide an example of the data you are importing.

Comment: I do not see how the body of this post relates to the title. Anyways, the documentation provides plenty of info for the keywords "import", "odd", "even". Moreover, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html contains many suggestions to manipulate lists.

Answer (score 3):

You should provide the data and samples of code when you ask a question here.

Anyway, generating the data:

```
l = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 20]
```

> {6, 7, 8, 5, 1, 5, 6, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 4, 9, 5, 3, 2}

there are many ways of splitting the list in odd and even:

```
{even, odd} = GatherBy[l, OddQ];
even
odd
```

> {6, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2}
>
> {7, 5, 1, 5, 9, 9, 9, 5, 3}

or

```
mask = OddQ@l;

odd = Pick[l, mask];

even = Pick[l, Not /@ mask];
```

or:

```
odd = Select[l, OddQ];

even = Select[l, EvenQ];
```

or

```
odd = Cases[l, _?OddQ];

even = Cases[l, _?EvenQ];
```